# Ive not made a VBS Script before but i want copy a file from our server to local hard drives on clients and have made this:

Tags: vbscript, winlogon

I've made a logon vbs (first ever) so when someone logs on to the domain it copies a file from a network drive to each local machine. Would this work (as long as the directories are correct)?

```
<% 
dim filesys
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists("W:\Student Shared Area\SBN\registration.xml") Then
  filesys.CopyFile "W:\Student Shared Area\SBN\registration.xml"  _
    , "C:\Program Files\New-Media-Learning\Logicator\"
End If
%>
```

Comment: How are you doing the copy? Is it from a mapped drive or a network share?

Comment: its from a mapped network drive (its a shared folder on the server though - not a complete drive)

Comment: Are the mapped drives persistent or are they set up via a batch file or similar on logon?

Comment: the drives are persistant to the user via groups set up in AD. if theyre a member of the group, the log on script adds the drive to the user everytime they log on

Comment: how do i show you what ive got already as i dont know if its even close. has to be a vbs as .bats are blocked.

this is what i had - it didnt appear above:

"<% 
dim filesys
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists("W:\Student Shared Area\SBN\registration.xml") Then
   filesys.CopyFile "W:\Student Shared Area\SBN\registration.xml", "C:\Program Files\New-Media-Learning\Logicator\"
End If
%>"

Comment: Sounds like it should work...

Comment: Just edit your post and paste in the code. If you add 4 spaces to each line it will appear as code when posted.

Comment: <% 

dim filesys

set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If filesys.FileExists("W:\Student Shared 

Area\SBN\registration.xml") Then

   filesys.CopyFile "W:\Student Shared Area\SBN\registration.xml", "C:\Program Files\New-Media-Learning\Logicator\"


End If
%>

Comment: The code looks fine. Is this going to sit in the user's startup folder?

Comment: thanks and its going to be applied by group policy. thanks

Comment: The only potential snags I can think of would be the user not being set up to run scripts or a problem within the GPO. Does it have to be a VBS? It would be easy enough to achieve what you want to do with a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two potential issues with your code:

- Drive `W:` is not (yet) mapped when the logon script runs. This won't be an issue when you map the drive before copying the file, but it might still be better to use a UNC path for the source:

  `filesys.CopyFile "\\server\share\Student Shared Area\SBN\registration.xml", "C:\Program Files\New-Media-Learning\Logicator\"`

  Personally I'd prefer [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), though, if that's an option for you.
- Users don't have write permissions on `C:\Program Files\New-Media-Learning\Logicator\` (the logon script runs in the user's context). This can be mitigated by [changing permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756952%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on that folder with a GPO.